# Cannot ping via second interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, ping

My RHEL7.6 box has two network interfaces, hard-wired ethernet and a USB wifi dongle. I downloaded the D-link driver, compiled the kernel module and modprobed it to install it.

Doing so gives me three `ip a` entries in total:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 52:54:00:4c:f5:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.250.125/24 brd 192.168.250.255 scope global noprefixroute dynamic ens3
   valid_lft 602997sec preferred_lft 602997sec
3: ens5f7u3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1460 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:ad:24:45:1c:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.1.68/24 brd 172.17.1.255 scope global dynamic ens5f7u3
   valid_lft 43198sec preferred_lft 43198sec
```

With ens3 being the ethernet. I can connect to a wireless network with wpa_supplicant just fine. I set the metrics manually with the sysconfig/network-scripts files so that the ethernet is always preferred. Then I used `dhclient ens5f7u3` to get that interface's IP address.

My `netstat -rn` output is then the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.250.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens3
0.0.0.0         172.17.1.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens5f7u3
172.17.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens5f7u3
192.168.250.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens3
```

If I now ping something on the internet, say 8.8.8.8, I get the usual successful output. If I use the `-I` flag on the ping, to specify the ens5f7u3 interface, the ping command just hangs forever, with no responses.

To avoid an [X/Y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), what I am trying to do is use the ethernet adapter to do all of my standard networking, and use the wifi adapter to periodically connect briefly to certain networks for auditing purposes. The wifi adapter will spend most of its time unconnected.

I need to be able to execute networking commands via the adapter, with ideally no interruption to the ethernet connection. I think that adding a static route for the networks I want to contact, and making them go via the wifi interface, is the right way to go. Is this correct? I would also need those routes to appear *above* the default 0.0.0.0 via ens3 route, right?

Comment: That's a FAQ: You can't have two connections to "the Internet" at the same time. Two default routes don't work, no matter what you to do the metric. If the use case is to periodically connect briefly to certain networks, the probably best solution is to setup a **network namespace**, move the wifi adapter to this namespace, and run the "auditing" processes in this namespace. There are already other answers describing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a colleague assist me and it turns out that the solution to this is to add a static route to the hosts on the internet, but to make sure that the metric is lower than the ethernet 0.0.0.0 route's metric.

Comment: Usually metric is irrelevant _unless_ the destination is the same for both routes. When destinations differ, routes are prioritized by their specifity (prefix length), so your host /32 or network routes will always be more specific than the default 0.0.0.0/0 route, even without any metric tweaking.

Comment: It's possible I misconfigured the routes the first time, but either way I've got something to work with here.